# How to call a function inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, iframe

I've made a function in wordpress with which I call an id into every post thru a shortcode. The function is:

```
function myshortcode_imdbid( ){
   $id = dt_get_meta('ids');
   return trim($id, 't');
}
add_shortcode( 'post_imdbid', 'myshortcode_imdbid' );
```

This function will print in every post a different id made of digits like: 232121

What I want to do is to call that ID into an iframe, do you have any idea on how to do that. Placing the shortcode inside the iframe won't work.

The iframe is always the same, only the ID is not the same. The iframe looks like:

```
<iframe class="API" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" data-apikey="XXXXXXXXXXXX" data-imdbid="HERE I MUST CALL MY ID"></iframe>
```

Do I need another function using that iframe and replace only the digits? If, so, any ideas?
Big thanks for reading this and I hope that someone can help.

Comment: did you try like this? `<iframe class="API" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" data-apikey="XXXXXXXXXXXX" data-imdbid="<?php echo do_shortcode('[post_imdbid]');?>"></iframe>`

Comment: I just did and I got this error: "A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (imdbid=&"

Comment: what is the value of [post_imdbid]?

Comment: The value of [post_imdbid] is different for every post, that's why I want to call the shortcode or function inside the iframe.

Comment: can you post the value of [post_imdbid] ?

Comment: Here's the output for a random post: 4686862

Comment: so you iframe output looks `<iframe class="API" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" data-apikey="XXXXXXXXXXXX" data-imdbid="4686862"></iframe>`?

Comment: Yes, but where is "4686862" I want to call the ID which is different for every post.

Comment: ok. what is the iframe url?

Comment: There is no URL, the iframe looks exactly like the above.

Comment: im not sure about this error

Comment: Isn't there any other way to call an iframe with that ID into every post?

Comment: Maybe to make a function with that iframe, since is the same for every post only the ID is different, call the ID and then the function into every post?

Comment: i tried with above the iframe code. I dont get any error. seems some other issue.

Comment: can you share me the site url to check?

Comment: The website is not yet live.

Comment: I can give you teamviewer if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed. the user using adsense plugin. the adsense plugin doent support the php in admin settings textbox. 
so it is fixed by adding the below code in single-post.php

```
  <iframe class="API" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" data-apikey="XXXXXXXXXXXX" data-imdbid="<?php echo do_shortcode('[post_imdbid]');?>"></iframe>
```